# Unity | Multitouch with phics2D Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, multi-touch

I created the sprites with images on my scene and i made work like buttons. All i want is that the all buttons are working simultaneously like multitouch screen. The code below is what i've done from now on. I use the TouchList which have gameobjects. I supposed the TouchList.Count would increase. However, the TouchList.Counts always show (number)1. 
I definitely can't touch two gameObjects in same time because the state of first touched gameobject is changed to "Exit". How can i add touched gameObjects in TouchList?

Please let me know how can i fix this code.

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

        touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
        touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
        touchList.Clear();

        Vector2 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit1 = Physics2D.Raycast(pos, Vector2.zero);

        //foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        if (hit1.collider != null) {
            GameObject recipient = hit1.transform.gameObject;
            touchList.Add(recipient);
            //Debug.Log ("recipient : " + hit1.transform.gameObject);
            Debug.Log ("I'm hitting "+hit1.collider.name);
            Debug.Log ("touchList.Count : " + touchList.Count);
            //recipient.SendMessage("OnColliderHit",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchDown",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
                recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchUp",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchStay",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }

        }                                                   
        //}
        foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld) {
            if (!touchList.Contains(g)) {
                g.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my modified code. It works well.:-)

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

        touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
        touchList.CopyTo(touchesOld);
        touchList.Clear();

        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
            Debug.Log ("touch.position : " + touch.position.ToString());
            Vector2 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            RaycastHit2D hit1 = Physics2D.Raycast(pos, Vector2.zero);
            if (hit1.collider != null) {
                GameObject recipient = hit1.transform.gameObject;
                touchList.Add(recipient);
                //Debug.Log ("recipient : " + hit1.transform.gameObject);
                Debug.Log ("I'm hitting "+hit1.collider.name);
                Debug.Log ("touchList.Count : " + touchList.Count);
                //recipient.SendMessage("OnColliderHit",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchDown",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);                 
                }
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchUp",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);                   
                }
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                    recipient.SendMessage("OnTouchStay",hit1.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }

            }                                                   
        }
        foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld) {
            if (!touchList.Contains(g)) {
                g.SendMessage("OnTouchExit",SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
}
```